# How to display values from one column when some condition is met in another column in R

Tags: r

I would like from R to give me something like a report on the end of my script, but I coudn´t find the proper function or question, because I am not a native english speaker.
I have a data frame with multiple column with several hundred rows. I am curious whether it is possible to reporting/getting results from R in such a way, that R will report to me only some specific cell from one column if some condition is met in another one. At the moment I am doing it with scrolling through a data frame after the `edit()` or `fix()` function.

Here is one reproducible example:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(10L, 11L, 13L, 1L), .Label = c("1.5.2005", 
"10.5.2005", "11.5.2005", "12.5.2005", "13.5.2005", "14.5.2005", 
"15.5.2005", "16.5.2005", "2.5.2005", "28.4.2005", "29.4.2005", 
"3.5.2005", "30.4.2005", "4.5.2005", "5.5.2005", "6.5.2005", 
"7.5.2005", "8.5.2005", "9.5.2005"), class = "factor"), Day = 118:121, 
    A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), B = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "0,94", "0,96", "0,98", "1,00", "1,01", "1,02", "1,03", "1,04", 
    "1,05"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", "Day", "A", 
"B"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

For example, the first occurence of number 1 in column A is on 1.5.2005 (and the day when it was reached was the 121-th day in a year) so I would like to R write something like:

```
Start A: 1.5.2005
Day: 121
```

And than if column B reach 1,00, than I would like to get something like

```
B reached: 7.5.2005
```

I tried It through `ifelse` and `print`, but that doesn´t worked

Comment: This is pretty basic [`[` extraction](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm sure there is a way to get it to print those things, but to get a data frame with just the observations you want is much easier.

To get the first occurrence of each date, you can use `split` in combination with `head`.

```
# Split the data on dates
data <- split(data, data$Date)
# Find the first occurrence of each date
data <- head(data, n=1)
# Bind them all back together into one data.frame
do.call('rbind', data)
```

To get only rows where B is '1,00' you can do several things. The easiest is to use my favorite package `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- filter(data, B == '1,00')
```

You could also just use the logical indexing native to data.frames.

```
data <- data[data$B == '1,00',]
```